# Replace white space with a dash using javascript inside a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to format a bunch of auto generated links containing white spaces, into versions where the white spaces have been replaced by "-" (dash) like this:

```
<a id="replacewhitespace" href="/properties-for-sale in Los Angeles">Los Angeles</a>
```

Changed into:

```
<a id="replacewhitespace" href="/properties-for-sale-in-Los-Angeles">Los Angeles</a>
```

The white space breaks the links.

I'm quite new to javascript, and been trying a bunch of stuff from researching online, but i can't seem to find a way to target the "href" part of a link. Up until now i managed to put the following together, but it only changes "normal" text (seen in the front-end). I need to target the html/href part.

```js
var orignalstring = document.getElementById("replacewhitespace").innerHTML;
var newstring = orignalstring.replace("","-");
document.getElementById("replacewhitespace").innerHTML = newstring;
```

```html
<li><span class="property-type">Penthouses</span> for sale in <span id="property-area"><a id="replacewhitespace" href="/properties-for-sale in Los Angeles">Los Angeles</a></span></li>
```

Can anyone help/guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You can use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set any attribute, like href. Also, for replacing, you probably want [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), instead of replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't need to modify the innerHTML, just use [Element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and [Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)
- Use [String.prototype.replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) or [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) using the *Global* `g` flag for the RegExp part
- Find all your elements with space inside a `href` attribute by using the Attribute `[href*=' ']` selector:

```js
const elsHrefWithSpaces = document.querySelectorAll("[href*=' ']");

elsHrefWithSpaces.forEach(el => {
  el.setAttribute("href", el.getAttribute("href").replace(/ /g, "-"));
});
```

```html
<a id="replacewhitespace" href="/properties-for-sale in Los Angeles">Los Angeles</a>  
<br>
<a id="replacewhitespace" href="/some spaces here">Los Spaces</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to first decode the anchor's target (accessed via the `href` property) with `decodeURI`, then use `replaceAll`:

```js
var orignalstring = document.getElementById("replacewhitespace").href;
var newstring = decodeURI(orignalstring).replaceAll(" ","-");
document.getElementById("replacewhitespace").href = newstring;

console.log(newstring)
```

```html
<li><span class="property-type">Penthouses</span> for sale in <span id="property-area"><a id="replacewhitespace" href="/properties-for-sale in Los Angeles">Los Angeles</a></span></li>
```

Or more simply:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("replacewhitespace");
elem.href = elem.href.replaceAll("%20", "-")

console.log(elem.href)
```

```html
<li><span class="property-type">Penthouses</span> for sale in <span id="property-area"><a id="replacewhitespace" href="/properties-for-sale in Los Angeles">Los Angeles</a></span></li>
```

If you have multiple links, you can do:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a[href*=' ']").forEach(e => {
  e.href = e.href.replaceAll("%20", "-");
  console.log(e.href)
})
```

```html
<li><span class="property-type">Penthouses</span> for sale in <span id="property-area">'
<a id="replacewhitespace" href="/properties-for-sale in Los Angeles">Los Angeles</a>
<a id="replacewhitespace" href="/properties-for-sale in Los Angeles">Los Angeles</a>
</span></li>
```

Comment: Oh damn. It works, but only on one/the first instance of the faulty link. I need it to work on a list of links, with the same id (replacewhitespace).

I'll have to throw in the .each() method somewhere/somehow now right?

Comment: @emilianoD85 I've updated my answer to show you how

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys!

Just as the answers were coming in, i managed to do it this way by a little (!!! - spend 2 hours prior to this :-D ) tampering around in JSFiddle:

```js
function replace() {
    var aEl = document.getElementById('replacewhitespace');
    aEl.href = aEl.href.replaceAll('%20', '-');
}


replace();
```

```html
<a id="replacewhitespace" href="/penthouses for sale in Los Angeles">Los Angeles</a>
```

Works in the JSFiddle at least - i guess this will do the trick (?!).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) with a `' '` char

```js
var orignalstring = document.getElementById("replacewhitespace").getAttribute('href');
console.log(orignalstring)
var newstring = orignalstring.replaceAll(" ","-");
console.log(newstring)
document.getElementById("replacewhitespace").innerHTML = newstring;
```

```html
<li><span class="property-type">Penthouses</span> for sale in <span id="property-area"><a id="replacewhitespace" href="/properties-for-sale in Los Angeles">Los Angeles</a></span></li>
```